# how to change where the limits start

Tags: summation

> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^{2}} & \leq 1+\sum_{n=2}^{N} \frac{1}{n^{2}-n} \\
> &=1+\sum_{j=1}^{N-1} \frac{1}{n(n+1)}
> \end{aligned}
> $$

In this summation, the person changes the summation of expression
$\frac{1}{n^{2}-n}$ to $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$.  I understand that this works because he changed the limits of the expression too, but how did he come up with $\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$? 
Could someone please take me through how he got that?
  Thank you, and English isn't my first language -- Dutch is -- so apologies.

Comment: Welkom.  [Hier](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023) is a MathJax tutorial.  Did you mean $1/(n^2+n)$?  It's a telescoping sum because $\dfrac1{n(n+1)}=\dfrac1n-\dfrac1{n+1}$

Comment: Dank je wel, meneer.. I will stick to English so rest of people can understand.. I have reposted the image, I have previously posted the wrong one.. could you you look at it again?

Comment: Oh, that's a different image; I think the summand indexed by $j$ should be $\dfrac1{j(j+1)}$, simply substituting $j+1$ for $n$

Comment: but what about the limits, don't we need to consider that too when substituiting?

Comment: yes, we do; that's why $n$ goes from $2$ to $N$, while $j$ goes from $1$ to $N-1$

Comment: je bent geweldig meneer

Comment: can we always do this substituition with any expression?

Comment: as long as the things being summed stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution $j=n-1$, it can be seen that $$\sum\limits_{n=2}^N\dfrac1{n(n-1)}=\sum\limits_{j=1}^{N-1}\dfrac1{(j+1)j}.$$

Comment: could I sub n as anything wanted?

Comment: I don't know what you had in mind to substitute, but for example you could say $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-2}\dfrac1{(k+2)(k+1)}$, etc.

Comment: Hoe dan ook, ik snap het, uw hulp wordt op prijs gesteld